# Tools framework for single page application (web site)

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, singlepage

Good day!

There is a number of similar questions here, but I'm particulary interested in such aspects of building single-page web applications:

- What server components are well suited for a big number of AJAX requests (maybe, Node.js)? My server platform is *nix (Debian) and PHP.
- When and how I need to replace AJAX with COMET and can I use the same server side?
- What javascript frameworks can help me to organize client-side (I mean MVC, MVVM, client templates)?

Any good points on overal approaches and architecture patterns are really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: good question, but it will be impossible to pick a single answer and call it correct

Comment: I think question which points me to relevant resources on this three topics will be correct...

Comment: Maybe you should break this up into separate more focused questions. The way it is right now, it requires a long write up, more time than I'm willing to dedicate. These issues you're talking about are in the mind of most web architects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From various blogs, it seems like Angular JS will cater for the most of the `SPA` needs

[Angular and Durandal Converge](http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/04/angular-and-durandal-converge.html)

Rob Eisenberg says:

> I would join the AngularJS 2.0 Core Team and help to design and implement AngularJS 2.0, bringing all my experience with Caliburn.Micro and Durandal into the mix.

---

From [Compare Durandal to Angular, Not Knockout to Angular](http://www.johnpapa.net/compare-durandal-to-angular-not-knockout-to-angular/)

> Knockout is a data binding library. It’s not a SPA framework.
>
> Drundal Vs Angular: They solve the same problems (in different ways of course). They both have routing, animations, view orchestration, dependency management, as well as data binding.
>
> Durandal is a natural progression from Knockout because Durandal uses Knockout. Durandal uses Knockout for data binding because its solid, very widespread, and reliable. Angular rolled their own data binding.

Also refer:

1. [Create an Angular App in Seconds with Hot Towel](http://www.johnpapa.net/hot-towel-angular/)
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1896043.aspx?What+to+choose+e+g+Hot+Towel+or+Angular+JS+
3. [How to master AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333857/how-to-master-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) provides a great way to create single page applications. This allows for our site to feel more and more like a native mobile application since we have a single page app.

It provides typical  routing using AngularJS routing .For advanced routing we have an excellent routing module called [ui-router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site), it supports nested routing and a lot more.

Also, it provides a [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module that animates page changes.

Also, we use the [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) modular script loader, which improves the speed and quality of the code.

Answer (score 1):

For a front-end MVC:
javascriptmvc.com
amplifyjs.com if you want to organize ajax requests

I would also agree that Node.js is particularly good if you are doing a lot of AJAX, as you are always just dealing with JSON objects - no conversions necessary. Plus it is very fast. With that said, any Ruby, PHP, Python framework would be perfectly capable as well.