# How to master AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and I find it a bit awkward. The easy stuff is very easy, but the advanced things are significantly harder (directives, provider / service / factory...)

The [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api) isn't very helpful for someone who's just starting to learn those things; and I find myself constantly searching for directives for things I need instead of writing my own.

I tried [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) and I was much more productive with it, but the API is still being changed significantly so I prefer skipping it for now.

Are there any better resources to get into AngularJS properly?

Comment: Since the question is locked, I'd like to add a little gem i've found: http://thinkster.io. in their own words: "We love AngularJS, but it was a pain to learn, so we've picked out & created the best resources for you to learn from. It's free, simple, and awesome."

Comment: I had the same experience so I created a tutorial series that eases you into Angular. I find the best way to learn is by doing so I walk you through creating an app step by step. Only introducing concepts as necessary to build the app. Each step is accompanied with a JSFiddle where you can review and experiment with the code. By the end you should be able to create your own app from scratch. You can find it at: http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2013/12/how-to-make-email-web-app-using-angular.html

Answer (score 202):

This is the most comprehensive AngularJS learning resource repository I've come across:

[**AngularJS-Learning**](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning)

To pluck out the best parts (in recommended order of learning):

- http://www.egghead.io/ - Series of short, to the point AngularJS videos
- [AngularJS Cheatsheet](http://www.cheatography.com/proloser/cheat-sheets/angularjs/) - regularly updated cheatsheet [latest update 13th February, 2013]
- [On nested scopes](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html) - Points out possible problems when using scope
  inheritance (references a good [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=29m19s) by Misko Hevery that you should
  also watch)
- [Dependency injection](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) - Official developer guide on
  DI
- [Dependency injection](http://dailyjs.com/2013/05/23/angularjs-injection/) - More on AngularJS dependency injection
- ["Service or Factory?"](http://iffycan.blogspot.com/2013/05/angular-service-or-factory.html) - Differences between the various types of
  providers
- [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) - Official developer guide on directives
- [Directives](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/) - The hitchhiker's guide to the directive
- [Project structure](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) - Check out this app
- [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) - Must use components for any UI development
- [UI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) - From-scratch JS re-implementations of bootstrap
  components as AngularJS directives
- [Full-Spectrum Testing with AngularJS and Karma](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html)
- [Bonus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1218080) - Data binding in AngularJS, explained by Misko Hevery himself.

Comment: Here's another intro video [Introduction to Angular.js in 50 Examples (part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: Some great links above - keep an eye on http://angularjs.guru/ I was going to get the domain myself which is how I stumbled across it, fairly new so not much on it yet but by the looks of it they could be pretty useful.

Answer (score 78):

Try out these videos [egghead.io](http://egghead.io) They are awesome to get started

Comment: I noticed it doesn't seem to have one on data bindings.  Do you know any good resources for learning this aspect?  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianArmstrong I might be a little late to the party, but make sure to check out lesson #1, "Binding": http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-binding

Answer (score 23):

For a comprehensive and continually growing collection of links check [AngularJS-Learning](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning), a github repo that collects resources, links and interesting blog posts.

I've found very helpful the tutorials and videos on the [AngularJS youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs). They go from the mostly basic stuff to some advanced topics, a good way to start.

The official [twitter](https://twitter.com/angularjs) and [google+](https://plus.google.com/+AngularJS/posts) accounts are a good way to follow news and get some nice links. Also check the [AngularJS Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular).

A nice aggregator of news/link is [angularjsdaily.com](http://www.angularjsdaily.com/).

Also there're some new books out there, so you can keep an eye on your favourite online library.

Answer (score 16):

The #angularjs IRC channel on freenode.net is a great way to get real-time responses.

Advice for getting help via IRC:

1. Have a relatively specific question to ask.
2. If possible, demonstrate your issue using [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).
3. Pick "prime time" hours to ask (Mid-afternoon to evening, EST works well for me.)
4. Don't pop in, ask a question, and leave 2 minutes later when someone doesn't answer immediately. Most of us only check IRC periodically.

Answer (score 16):

The video [AngularJS Fundamentals In 60-ish Minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM) provides a very good introduction and overview.

I would also highly recomend the [AngularJS book from O'Reilly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449344852), mentioned by @Atropo.

Comment: Many reviews of the book from O'Reilly indicate that it has a very large number of errors including coding errors. The code straight from the book will often not work. The book is not recommended.

Answer (score 8):

Please keep an eye on the mailing list for problems/solutions discussed by community members. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/angular . It's been really useful to me.

Answer (score 6):

Concerning more advanced usage, I find these two pages a must read:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the **question** and **title** of this book: http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book

[image]

Comment: This book started out nice but eventually headed the wrong way. The book shows you how to build a single page app using Angular but introduces a ton of non-relevant technologies that get you bogged down: node.js, mongodb, unit testing, and so on. You shouldn't have to read 375 pages to learn AngularJS. I don't recommend this book for learning AngularJS.