# jQuery to AngularJS using Yeoman

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, yeoman

We developed a web app using jQuery for 6 weeks and we need to re-do that using AngularJS. Please help me with the below stuffs,
1. What's the delta that I need to consider while estimating?
2. I'm planning to use Yeoman stack for client, Do I need to consider separate effort for the client infrastructure?

Thanks,
Karthik.

Answer (score 3):

1.
`AngularJS` can use `jQuery`, so you can use your old functions.
When you start a project with `AngularJS` you need to modify also `HTML` template.

This is the most comprehensive AngularJS learning resource repository I've come across:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17363901/1875004)
and [follow me](https://twitter.com/ririlepanda)

2.
Yeoman is a perfect tool to manage your client project. You can save time with this. You need to consider separate effort for the client infrastructure.

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: I would warn against using exiting jquery code in angular. If one wants to do this, better stay with jquery, why add additional angular dependency. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Moving from a typical jquery based app to a Angular based app is a major refactoring exercise. AngularJS using jquery does not warrant a simpler migration process. In fact the development philosophy for jquery and angularjs are poles apart.

AngularJS is designed keeping in mind seperation of concern. Your DOM manipulation, css updates an all are not mixed with your client side code. The UI for AngularJS is model driven, changes is model causes UI to update (using databinding). Lot's of boilerplate code that is required in jquery can be done away with angular. In fact this refactoring will for sure reduce your code base.

I sincerely suggest you to look at a sample example for something build with AngularJS, such as [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/), [AngularJS tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to get a idea about it's functionality\capabilities.

And another thing to consider here would be the learning curve involved. I pretty much aggree with what this guys [says](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-My-Experience-With-AngularJS-The-Super-heroic-JavaScript-MVW-Framework.htm)

But at the end it is worth as the code produced is far more structured as compared to jquery code.