# Prerequisite for learning Angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to learn Angular for working on a project.
I am a backend Java/Spring developer
I have knowledge of HTML and Javascript. I have also worked on basic Knockout.js.

What are the prerequisite for learning Angular ?

Comment: Like every single programming language/framework: Patience, perseverance and a tutorial. If you already know the basics to code then you have 80% done.

Comment: For beginner  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKkUN-mJtPQ

Comment: Build things in your free time / or at work if you can. All you need to do is get your hands dirty and get experience yourself. All the video tutorials wont help you if you just sit and watch. You really have to implement things on your own, like small applications that come into your mind. Maybe a task or time tracker, a simple todo list which you could extend with features later. Egghead has great videos for Angular 1. If you can afford to buy a really good course, check out Todd Motto's course https://courses.toddmotto.com/pages/courses.

Comment: start looking in to this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17363901/6449750

Comment: This question shouldn't be closes even though it is opinion based, coming to this question and reading the answers helped me gathering bits and pieces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You see this 1 hour [Angular 7 tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV2MXOygDTM) which explains everything what you need to start with Angular. If you can watch you will have a better understanding of things.

So in all you need five important pre-requisites for Angular :-

1. You need to know JavaScript in depth.You should have crystal clear concepts  on [Javascript closures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYrtnS3X_Lw) , [Javascript IIFE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5EntfMeIIQ) , prototyping and so on.
2. A good understanding of  [NodeJs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LF_43_Mqnw) is must and especially how to use NPM ( Node package manager).
3. You need to know typescript.
4. A good understanding of module loaders , binders , commonjs , AMD , UMD , ES5 and so on.
5. This point is not compulsory its optional. If you know VS code you can learn lot of internals of Angular. As every developer has his own favorite IDE and Editor this step is optional. I would still suggest do your first couple of practicals using VS code and then proceed with your favorite IDE.

Below is the road-map of the pre-requisites and how to learn Angular. You can start learning Angular pre-requisites from this [Learn Angular Step by Step article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1207118/Learn-Angular-Tutorial) which covers around 11 labs in depth.

And yes if you are preparing for Angular interview jobs you can check video [50 Angular Interview Questions with Answers.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-jeoyDJDsSM)

[image: Angular Learning Pre-requiste]

Answer (score 9):

Moderate knowledge of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Basic Model-View-Controller (MVC) concepts.

The Document Object Model (DOM).

JavaScript functions, events, and error handling.

**HTML :** Most of the templates we create in angularJS is in the form of handcrafted htmls. i.e. So you must know that what are forms in html and what are tags ng-form etc.

**CSS :** While hand crafting template you should require css to make more attractive UI design.

**DOM :** Document object model and how document is created. If you have good jquery background you can easily pick up this part.

**Object Oriented JavaScript:** Global name space: AngularJS heavily uses javascript name space. i.e.

Object Oriented JavaScript: Inheritance: Inheritance is very important concept in JavaScript. Inheritance is heavily used in all the frameworks in JavaScript. i.e.

```
var Employee = function(fname) {
   this.fname =fname;
   console.log("Your first name is "+fname);
} 
var fistEmployee = new Employee("John");

var secondEmployee = new Employee("Jim");

fistEmployee.prototype.lastname = function(lname) {
      this.lname=lname;
      console.log("Your last name is "+lname);
}
```

So using prototype you can easily add properties on the fly.

**Model View Whatever(MVW):** This term is used heavily by all AngularJS developers. It is coined by Google. It is simple MVC concept.

**Separation of Concern(SOC):** SOC concept is heavily used in AngularJS. In angularJS all the controllers, directive, services and factories are made for SOC. It provide more lean and cleaner code. Also re usability automatically increases if you use SOC concept.

**Promises :** Promises are nothing but callbacks. When you call any AngularJS service it will be called asynchronously. When response is send from service callback hold the response and do the needful.

**Test Driven Development :** Best thing about AngularJS is you can easily write test script so that when you go home, you can easily have sound sleep.

Answer (score 2):

The most prerequisite for learning latest Angularjs (version 5.x right now - https://angular.io/tutorial) is:

**TYPESCRIPT AND SOME OOPS LIKE INHERITENCE!**

Everyone knows that the basics of HTML/CSS/JS is the prerequisite of everything in web development.

Today, Many people are diving into learning angularjs without knowing or just a bit about typescript. This will make learning angular a hell of a trouble, so i thought to put my 2 cents here.

Also the top most selected answer does not emphasize on the importance of learning Typescript, it's weird.

Typescript is not known to many beginners in web development. Even it's declaration is confusing if you do not study it first.

So please start from here if you wanna learn AngularJS:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you should know about patterns of desing like MVC on angular. that's the common.

And how to use properly some parts of angular, i'll share you a guide that i've found of good practics coding in angular.

Hope this help you to start coding on Angular

[Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)